# Code to pull information before and after matching substring

Tags: python, regex

I tried building the regex in regex101. In regex101 the code is working but when I am trying to run that cod in Python it is not working. Can anyone please help me in correcting the mistake?
The code is

```
> for file in glob.glob('*TxtMsg*'):
>     with open(file) as f:
>         names = []
>         contents = f.read()
>         if 'Nbsequence::findtest System.SerialNumber=' in contents:
>             print(re.match(r'(\w*)(?: Active\) Nbsequence::findtest System.SerialNumber=)(\d+)', contents))
```

Code Identifies required files from a location
Read it one by one to identify it has required info or not
If it has then it check for regex patter to extract required info.

Sample data is

```
succeeded to get serial number, Module = ABC Active, SerialNumber = 8212____________
[00007841][2022-07-04 16:48:30.581][Info][P00800 SunnyDay][T18304]: DayModule::FetchSerialNumber, fetching via web service..., SlotId = 1, IpAddress = 156.185.1.21, Port = 3990
[00007842][2022-07-04 16:48:30.597][Info][P00800 SunnyDay][T13844]: (ABC Active) Nbsequence::findtest (System.SerialNumber) 
[00007843][2022-07-04 16:48:30.597][Info][P00800 SunnyDay][T13844]: (ABC Active) Nbsequence::findtest System.SerialNumber=8212____________
[00007844][2022-07-04 16:48:30.606][Info][P00800 SunnyDay][T13844]: (PQR Active) Nbsequence::findtest (System.SerialNumber) 
[00007845][2022-07-04 16:48:30.608][Info][P00800 SunnyDay][T13844]: (PDIM Active) Nbsequence::findtest (System.SerialNumber) 
[00007846][2022-07-04 16:48:30.613][Info][P00800 SunnyDay][T13844]: (PQR Active) Nbsequence::findtest System.SerialNumber=8198____________
[00007847][2022-07-04 16:48:30.615][Info][P00800 SunnyDay][T13844]: (WPC Activ
```

Appreciate your help in this

Result will be (Underlined in Blue)
ABC: 8212,
PQR: 8198

[image]

Regex Screen[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add your error log? so we can see what its saying is going wrong? from what I see now the only thing I can think of is making sure to add `open(file ,"r")`

Comment: Hello Christian,

Thank you for looking into it... 

When I run code in Python I just get "None". 
I have included my code to add regex101 screenshot as well. 
I need Group 1 and Group 2 info

Comment: Did you miss adding `r` before your regex to make it as raw? Else you need to handle escaping characters

Comment: Hello pushpesh, Thank you for looking into it

I modified the code and it the same..
I added screen shot as well

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
import re

s = """\
succeeded to get serial number, Module = ABC Active, SerialNumber = 8212____________
[00007841][2022-07-04 16:48:30.581][Info][P00800 SunnyDay][T18304]: DayModule::FetchSerialNumber, fetching via web service..., SlotId = 1, IpAddress = 156.185.1.21, Port = 3990
[00007842][2022-07-04 16:48:30.597][Info][P00800 SunnyDay][T13844]: (ABC Active) Nbsequence::findtest (System.SerialNumber) 
[00007843][2022-07-04 16:48:30.597][Info][P00800 SunnyDay][T13844]: (ABC Active) Nbsequence::findtest System.SerialNumber=8212____________
[00007844][2022-07-04 16:48:30.606][Info][P00800 SunnyDay][T13844]: (PQR Active) Nbsequence::findtest (System.SerialNumber) 
[00007845][2022-07-04 16:48:30.608][Info][P00800 SunnyDay][T13844]: (PDIM Active) Nbsequence::findtest (System.SerialNumber) 
[00007846][2022-07-04 16:48:30.613][Info][P00800 SunnyDay][T13844]: (PQR Active) Nbsequence::findtest System.SerialNumber=8198____________
[00007847][2022-07-04 16:48:30.615][Info][P00800 SunnyDay][T13844]: (WPC Active)"""

pat = re.compile(r"\((.*?) Active\).*?System\.SerialNumber=(\d+)")


for result in pat.findall(s):
    print(result)
```

Prints:

```
('ABC', '8212')
('PQR', '8198')
```

---

**Note:** `re.match` tries to match the line from the beginning and `\w` doesn't match space (you have space in your datetime part of line).

Comment: ha thankyou, I had to go lookup the different common re functions to see that I should have been using `search`, and then how `findall` could have made my code allot more compact and streamlined

Comment: Thank you Andrej, It worked... Can you help me to understand the flow. I am at very beginner level in Python

Comment: @Sanjeev The link to Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/dgQd3d/1 . By default `.*` is greedy, that is `a.*b` matches `aaabaab` (note the `b` in the middle). With `a.*?b` matches the first `b` - `aaab`

Answer (score 0):

edited your regex a little bit, seems to work for me

```
re.match(r'\(\w*(?: Active\) Nbsequence::findtest System.SerialNumber=)(\d+)', contents)
```

[image]

here is this same regex but with the name and code added to a dictionary as requested:

```
dictionary = {}
text = '(ABC Active) Nbsequence::findtest (System.SerialNumber) (ABC Active) Nbsequence::findtest System.SerialNumber=8212______ (PQR Active) Nbsequence::findtest (System.SerialNumber) (PDIM Active) Nbsequence::findtest (System.SerialNumber) (PQR Active) Nbsequence::findtest System.SerialNumber=8196____________'
matches = re.findall(r'\((\w*) Active\) Nbsequence::findtest System.SerialNumber=(\d+)', text)
for match in matches:
    dictionary[match[0]] = match[1]
print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Result is same.. It showing none only.. 
I wanted to extract Active name and Last no.

ABC

Comment: can you take a look at the screenshot and let me know if this is equivalent to what your trying to do? besides filtering for only the name and number afterwords, the strings you are tryng to match with just look like this?

Comment: Thank you Christian,

The code you shared works when we iterate line by link. Can we have have search it on the complete documents at once without iterating line by line. 

Also as output i need a dictionary that just has Name and its serial no

ABC: 8212,
PQR: 8198

Comment: edited to add that in for you